# Is $\{1\}$ an open subset of $\{1,-1\}$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm sorry to ask this stupid question, but I really need someone to help clarify something. Thank you.

In determining whether a set is open or not, one must point out what topology is being used. In our case, we simply use the Euclidean distance function $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and then endow $\{1,-1\}$ with the metric topology. I claim that the singleton $\{1\}$ is an open set, since $1$ is an interior point of the singleton. On the other hand, this singleton is also closed because the space in question is Hausdorff. Is my reasoning correct? Thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: [*clopen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set)

Comment: This is correct. This topology is called the discrete topology on $\{-1,1\}.$  The discrete topology on a set $X$ is one where every subset is open (and hence every subset is also closed.)

Comment: (Unlike the case for doors, "open" and "closed" are orthogonal concepts for sets: all four combinations are possible!)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm not sure if the topology is discrete, because I didn't collect all subsets of $\{1,-1\}$ to construct a topology in the very beginning.

Comment: @steve It easy to show, however.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It seems that we are getting at the subject concerning metrizable spaces. And according to you, the distance function here can induce the discrete topology. If one wants to answer this question, will he/she need to show that every subset of $\{1,-1\}$ is open in the metric topology? Is it correct, Sir?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\{1\}$ is open as it equals the ball $B(1, 1)$ in the relative metric.

It's *also* closed as any singleton is a metric space (or as $\{-1\}$, its complement, is similarly open in $\{-1,1\}$ as well. So it's a [clopen](http://en.wikipedia.org/en/Clopen_set) set, no problem, this happens quite a lot.